# How to get unique jest spy in concurrent tests?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, react-hooks, spy

I am mocking a function (react hook) to return something for a unit test, and would like to verify with a spy that it has been called only once.

This works fine for regular tests, but when trying to add `test.concurrent.each`, the spy appears to be shared across tests and the toHaveBeenCalledTimes is set to the number of tests run.

I tried to create a unique spy for each test, but it doesn't seem to matter:

```
export const mockLazyQuery = (result: TQueryResult): jest.SpyInstance => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(Apollo, "useLazyQuery");

  spy.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    return [jest.fn(), result];
  });
  return spy;
};
```

```
import { mockLazyQuery } from "../test-utils";

describe("useHasScope", () => {
  it.concurrent.each([
    [Role.STUDENT, fakeStudent],
    [Role.TRAINER, fakeTrainer],
  ])("should redirect a %s user to the home page", async (role, me) => {
    const querySpy = mockLazyQuery({
      data: { me },
      error: undefined,
      loading: false,
    });
    myIdVar(me.id);
    const wrapper: React.FC = ({ children }) => (
      <MemoryRouter>{children}</MemoryRouter>
    );
    renderHook(() => useHasScope(""), { wrapper });
    expect(querySpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);   // <== Failing because other tests calling useLazyQuery are running concurrently 
  });
});
```

[image]

Any idea how to keep the mock and spy state private within a test and allow to run several similar tests concurrently ?

Comment: Hello do you try this : "beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });" could fix your problem maybe

Comment: @Lapach' I have jest.clearAllMocks() setup on beforeEach, but it doesn't fix the problem. My issue is related to tests being run concurrently and sharing the same spy.